# visualize a HashTable in java

Tags: java, hashtable, visualization, data-visualization

I have a hashtable  that contains the information about some book titles and the number of times each book is purchased. I want to draw a bar chart that can show this information visually. Is there any library or method in java that can do this?

```
HashTable<String, Integer> bookPurchaseTable=new HashTable<String, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaFX has bar chart capabilities. This page has a tutorial that should have enough information to get you started.
https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/bar-chart.htm

Also, You should probably use a HashMap instead of a HashTable if possible.

Use myHashMap.keySet() to get the keys, and then for each key, use myHashMap.get(key) to get the integer.

Comment: So I used that link and it helped me a lot. The only thing is that I have a hard time to use that code as a separate class in my program. (Example 7-1 Creating a Bar Chart with Three Series of Data)

Answer (score 0):

it's a big topic about Java UI deployment.
you can try [java swing tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/) first, and learn how to develop UI in java.

BTW, it's recommend to use HashMap not HashTable now.

hope you can enjoy the Java.

Comment: Actually, I am not a java programmer. I mostly use Python and specially R. Visualization in R is really easy. But I have found a nice source code in Java and that is why I am coding in Java.